# Is there a way for a Keras model to predict with precision around 14-17 of significant digits?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I've created simple Keras model (prediction, not classification or regression)

```
inpLayer = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,), dtype=tf.float64)
hiddenLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.atan, dtype=tf.float64)(inpLayer)
outputLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', dtype=tf.float64)(hiddenLayer)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inpLayer, outputLayer)
```

with Adam optimizer and I used Mean squared error as a loss function and using batch (offline) gradient descent. I have a small dataset (2 "rows").

x = [35., 49.]

y = [0., 1.]

Am I able to train this simple Neural Network on those features and labels? By "train" I mean: When the model predicts, it returns output close to the labels using whole float64. So the output should have 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision.

**Acceptable**: Output for 0 would be in range 9.9e-14 to 1.0e-17.
Output for 1 would be in range 1.0e+14 to 9.9e+17.

Is it even possible to train the Neural network like that or it is not?
If so, what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: What do you mean "*prediction, not classification or regression*"? *Everything is prediction (including classification and regression)...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but I want to predict number, not classify it or find the best fit as regression does...

Comment: So, did you train that neural network? What is the problem?

Comment: Yes I did, but I am not able to get desired results... I've used 200 000 epochs and still nothing..

Comment: Predict number is classification or regression, depending if number is integer or real numbers. Your case seems to be regression.

Comment: Since you want to "predict number", as you say, and you use the MSE loss, you are in a  regression setting indeed, as indicated by @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the data, for example use a normalization layer. You could also increase the number of neurons to get faster good results.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = [[35.], [49.]]
y = [[0.], [1.]]

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
normalization_layer.adapt(x)
inpLayer = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,), dtype=tf.float64)
norm = normalization_layer(inpLayer)
hiddenLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.atan, dtype=tf.float64)(norm)
outputLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', dtype=tf.float64)(hiddenLayer)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inpLayer, outputLayer)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, y, epochs=5000, batch_size=2, verbose=1)

model.evaluate([[35.], [49.]], [[0.], [1.]])
a,b = model.predict([[35.], [49.]])
print(a.astype(str), b.astype(str))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 5000/5000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.1910e-30
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 112ms/step - loss: 1.1910e-30
['9.43689570931383e-16'] ['0.9999999999999988']
```

Comment: I see, but why do I need 5000 times number 35. and 49.? I should be able to learn it on just 2 examples, Am I right?

Comment: @Majk Yes, but when you have more steps in one epoch, the fit method expects more data. You have to provide it the same 2 examples over and over again. You can use a generator for that, see my answer

Comment: Yea understand, but what if I want to use just steps_per_epoch=1 and batch_size=2, so called offline (batch) learning? With this example I can't get the wanted results (I mean ith steps_per_epoch=1 and batch_size=2)...